# get a variable from constructor

Tags: java

I used this code to verify a digital sign of a file, the constructor prints the context of the file but I wanted to know how to save the print as a variable , since a constructor uses only to "build" objects, this is the code:

```
public class VerifyMessage {
    private List<byte[]> list;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // The constructor of VerifyMessage class retrieves the byte arrays from the File and prints the message only if the signature is verified.
    public VerifyMessage(String filename, String keyFile) throws Exception {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        this.list = (List<byte[]>) in.readObject();
        in.close();

       System.out.println(verifySignature(list.get(0), list.get(1), keyFile) ? "VERIFIED MESSAGE" + "\n----------------\n" + new String(list.get(0)) : "Could not verify the signature.");      
    }
```

How can I "save" the System.out.println as a global member String variable outside of the constructor?
thanks ahead

Comment: Um...you could add a new `String` field to the class and assign it from `VerifyMessage()`.  By the way, Java coding conventions state that we don't name methods using uppercase letters for the first letter.

Answer (score 2):

Your class already contains a list field.

Similar to that, you declare a string field- and then you simply assign the value you are currently printing to that field.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VerifyMessage {
private List<byte[]> list;

Object variable = null;


public VerifyMessage(String filename, String keyFile) throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    this.list = (List<byte[]>) in.readObject();
    in.close();


    this.variable = this.verifySignature(list.get(0), list.get(1), keyFile);
}


private Object verifySignature(byte[] bs, byte[] bs2, String keyFile) {

    //
    return null;
}
```

}